# Getting error Use of uninitialized value $col2 in hash element at lol.pl line 13, <$f2> line 1

Tags: perl

I made a program to filter out the rows containing a value from a text file...i am getting this error

> Use of uninitialized value $col2 in hash element at lol.pl line 13,
>    line 1.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %keys;
open( my $f1, '<', 'jump.txt' ) or die("Cannot open jump.txt: $!");
while (<$f1>) {
    chomp;
    $keys{$_} = 1;
}
close($f1);
open( my $f2, '<', 'sym.txt' ) or die("Cannot open sym.txt: $!");
while (<$f2>) {
    my ( undef, $col2, undef ) = split( ' ', $_ );
    print if ( $keys{$col2} );
}
close($f2);
```

jump.txt:

```
a
b
c
```

sym.txt:

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
e   5
```

desired output:

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

Comment: then [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) ruturns less than 2 elements. Make sure your input file always has 2 or more elements on each line

Comment: sym.txt: http://pastebin.com/tr8ABJq8

Comment: jump.txt http://pastebin.com/C8KkG3Vp

Comment: Change `print if ($keys{$col2});` to `print if (exists $keys{$col2});`. Since the hash is only used for validation, testing for existence of the key is sufficient for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) (as you should) you will get a warning when you try to use an uninitialized variable:

```
perl -wE 'my $x; say $x'
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $x in say at -e line 1.
```

In a list assignment, extra values are silently ignored and if you have too many variables, the extras get the value `undef`.

```
perl -wE 'my ($x, $y) = (2); say $y'
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $y in say at -e line 1.
```

In your case, it is likely that the problem is this line:

```
my(undef, $col2, undef) = split(' ', $_);
```

If `split` returns only a single item (or zero items), `$col2` will be undefined.

See also documentation on *"List value constructors"* in [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

**Edit:**

To get the desired output (seems like you need `$col1` and not `$col2`):

```
my $col1  = (split(' ', $_))[0];
print if $keys{$col1};
```

Comment: I would note `split (' ', $_);` is the default, so you can simply `split;` instead.